# How to create a bottom tab navigator with multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, react-native

My app has more bottom tab options than can comfortably fit on one row. React Navigation's createBottomTabNavigator can only create one row of tabs in the bottom menu, so is there a way to create a bottom tab menu with multiple rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have any idea what you want to achieve, this could help you out to work on it. Simply use a nested `createBototmTabNavigator`

```
const HomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  a: createBottomTabNavigator({
    b: {
      screen: B
    },
    c: {
      screen: C
    },
    d: {
      screen: D
    }
  })
})

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

EDIT

To create a "expand" tab which shows the second row, you use it like this

```
const HomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  a: {
    screen: A
    },
    expand: createBottomTabNavigator({
    c: {
      screen: C
    },
    d: {
      screen: D
    }
  })
})

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. This solution can create two rows in the bottom menu, but I would only like the second row to show if the user hits an "expand" tab. Is there a way to only have the second row show if the user chooses to expand the menu?

Comment: @RaghavGopalakrishnan I've edited my answer. That will only display the second row if they tap on the expand tab. Let me know if that worked

Comment: @RaghavGopalakrishnan glad it worked! please upvote and mark the answer as correct :)