# React Native bottom drawer navigation with sub menus?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, components, native

I am looking for a bottom navigator react native component that will allow me to have sub menus pop out of it?

I'm thinking of something that looks like this:

[React Native Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1OcJ.png)

I have a hard time believing this doesn't exist.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using something like `createBottomTabNavigator` from [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/)

That allows for bottom navigation but would also also you to create more than one row like your mock. See this link for more info: [How to create a bottom tab navigator with multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382690/how-to-create-a-bottom-tab-navigator-with-multiple-rows)

Comment: Great! No problem.